# I made a chat app with Node.JS and Socket IO. How do you upload to a domain?

Tags: html, node.js, web, upload, vs-web-site-project

I successfully made a chatroom that is based on node.JSs socket.io package. So I have basically one .html file in and a couple of .js files.

So basically what I have currently is the foundation for a website with a chat app.

My question is, is there something I need to think before uploading this to a domain? Will the chat app still be working when I upload it with something like say FileZilla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a webserver that at least runs runs node.js. There are some PaaS solutions out here you can check out here: https://geekflare.com/nodejs-hosting-platform/

For a small application I can recommend Heroku. What you have to do is described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

If you already have some webspace and this question isn't meant as the beginner level might sound, you need can upload your stuff with any software to your server.